# Truffle Deployment Error: has no network configuration for its current network id (97)

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment, truffle-compile

I'm having an issue deploying a contract with Truffle. The contract constructor takes 7 parameters which are all within the `2_deploy_xxx.js` file. However, every time I do, I get an error when I get to deploying the actual contract. The contract takes an oracle (AggregatorV3Interface from ChainLink). I'm stumped and wondered if anyone would be able to help me as I've stared at this for too long.

truffle-config.js

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
require('dotenv').config();

const BSC_DEPLOYER_KEY = process.env.BSC_DEPLOYER_KEY;
const BSC_TESTNET_DEPLOYER_KEY = process.env.BSC_TESTNET_DEPLOYER_KEY;

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*",
    },
    testnet: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(BSC_TESTNET_DEPLOYER_KEY, `https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545`, 0, 10),
      network_id: 97,
      confirmations: 10,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: true,
      from: 'address',
    },
    bsc: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(BSC_DEPLOYER_KEY, `https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org`),
      network_id: 56,
      confirmations: 10,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: true,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    'truffle-plugin-verify'
  ],
  api_keys: {
    etherscan: process.env.BSCSCAN_API_KEY
  },
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.6.12",
      settings: {
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true,
          runs: 999999
        },
      }
    },
  }
}
```

2_deploy_prediction.js

```
const BnbPricePrediction = artifacts.require("BnbPricePrediction");
const AggregatorV3Interface = artifacts.require("AggregatorV3Interface");

const ADMIN_ADDRESS = '';
const OPERATOR_ADDRESS = '';
const INTERVAL_BLOCKS = 100;
const BUFFER_BLOCKS = 20;
const MIN_BET_AMOUNT = 1000000000000000;
const ORACLE_UPDATE_ALLOWANCE = 300;

module.exports = function (deployer, network, accounts) {
    console.log(network);

    let adminAddress = ADMIN_ADDRESS;
    let operatorAddress = OPERATOR_ADDRESS;
    let intervalBlocks = INTERVAL_BLOCKS;
    let bufferBlocks = BUFFER_BLOCKS;
    let minBetAmount = MIN_BET_AMOUNT;
    let oracleUpdateAllowance = ORACLE_UPDATE_ALLOWANCE;

    deployer.deploy(AggregatorV3Interface);

    let oracle = AggregatorV3Interface.address

    deployer.deploy(
        BnbPricePrediction,
        oracle,
        adminAddress,
        operatorAddress,
        intervalBlocks,
        bufferBlocks,
        minBetAmount,
        oracleUpdateAllowance
    );
    console.table({
        BnbPricePrediction:BnbPricePrediction.address
    })
};
```

Truffle Error

```
2_deploy_prediction.js
======================
testnet

Error: BnbPricePrediction has no network configuration for its current network id (97).
    at Function.network (/Users/n0rden/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/contract/properties.js:108:1)
    at Function.getter (/Users/n0rden/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/contract/constructorMethods.js:282:1)
    at Function.get (/Users/n0rden/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/contract/properties.js:129:1)
    at Function.getter (/Users/n0rden/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/contract/constructorMethods.js:279:1)
    at module.exports (/Users/n0rden/tendie-prediction/migrations/2_deploy_prediction.js:36:47)
    at Migration._load (/Users/n0rden/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:56:1)
    at Migration.run (/Users/n0rden/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:203:1)
    at Object.runMigrations (/Users/n0rden/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:150:1)
    at Object.runFrom (/Users/n0rden/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:110:1)
    at Object.runAll (/Users/n0rden/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:114:1)
    at Object.run (/Users/n0rden/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:79:1)
    at runMigrations (/Users/n0rden/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate.js:263:1)
    at Object.run (/Users/n0rden/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate.js:228:1)
    at Command.run (/Users/n0rden/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:136:1)
```

Comment: Kindly show your truffle-config.js file

Comment: @mzaidi just added the truffle-config above

Comment: I think `deployer.deploy` is async and you aren't `await`ing for it.

Comment: @Ismael that wasn't the completely correct solution but it definitely led me to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The solution to my issue was removing AggV3Int as a required artifact, assigning the address of an already deployed oracle, and changing the deployer function to be async `await`ing deployer.deploy.

Comment: It would be nice if you can add a version of the migration script so they answer is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

What are the extra 2 parameters 0 and 10 with the testnet link? I think if you change
provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(BSC_TESTNET_DEPLOYER_KEY, `https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545`, 0, 10),

to

provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(BSC_TESTNET_DEPLOYER_KEY, `https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545`),

It should work.

Comment: If i do that I get the following:
```
"Migrations" -- Unknown address - unable to sign transaction for this address: "address".
```

Comment: Just confirming if BSC_DEPLOYER_KEY and BSC_TESTNER_DEPLOYER_KEY are the mnemonics of the address you are using to sign transactions?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: You havent defined this 'address' string anywhere that you have used for the from parameter. If you are using mnemonics from the same address then you dont need to specify from param. Place your actual address in place of the string address

Comment: I removed my actual address. 'address' above is just a placeholder